# Creating a list of set of pairs from existing list

Tags: list, scala, set

Let's say I have the following list:

```
val my_list = List("a","b","c","d")
```

I want the write a function `get_set_pairs` such that `get_set_pairs(my_list)` gives me:

```
List(Set("a","b"), Set("a","c"), Set("a","d"), Set("b","c"), Set("b","d"), Set("c","d"))
```

I know how to do this with a for-loop. I am trying to find a functional and efficient way of doing so

Thanks for your help

Comment: First, please follow naming conventions: `getSetPairs` this is not **Python**. - Second, why **Sets** of two elements? Just use a **Tuple**. Third, you can just use [`for` _comprehension_](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) to write a very similar code to an imperative `for` _loop_. - Last, if you [know the rules of the sugar syntax of `for`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-does-for--yield-work) you will see that you can write this very easily just using `flatMap`, `map` & `filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combinations` and map the entries to sets:

```
my_list.combinations(2).map(_.toSet).toList
// List[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] = List(Set(a, b), Set(a, c), Set(a, d), Set(b, c), Set(b, d), Set(c, d))
```